# Problem when reading a wavfile generated using gTTS

Tags: python, audio, text-to-speech

For my project I tried to use gTTS to generate an audio file from a String and then manipulate said audio, but when I tried to open it with some libraries (scipy and librosa), it says that the format is invalid. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

The code:

```
tts = gTTS('Semáforo Gran Vía a 100 metros', lang='es')

filename = 'Senal.mp3'
tts.save(filename)
#y, sr = librosa.load('Senal.mp3')
x = wavfile.read(filename)
```

The error(s):
Scipy

> File "C:/Users/Samuel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 108, in 
> conversion()

> File "C:/Users/Samuel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 25, in conversion
> x = wavfile.read(filename)

> File "C:\Users\Samuel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 650, in read
> file_size, is_big_endian = _read_riff_chunk(fid)

> File "C:\Users\Samuel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py", line 521, in _read_riff_chunk
> raise ValueError(f"File format {repr(str1)} not understood. Only "
> ValueError: File format b'\xff\xf3D\xc4' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported.

Librosa

> File "C:/Users/Samuel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 103, in 
> conversion()

> File "C:/Users/Samuel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 19, in conversion
> y, sr = librosa.load('Senal.mp3')

> File "C:\Users\Samuel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py", line 88, in inner_f
> return f(*args, **kwargs)

> File "C:\Users\Samuel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 174, in load
> y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)

> File "C:\Users\Samuel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py", line 198, in __audioread_load
> with audioread.audio_open(path) as input_file:

> File "C:\Users\Samuel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\audioread_*init*_.py", line 116, in audio_open
> raise NoBackendError()
> audioread.exceptions.NoBackendError

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine for me With Python=3.10.8, gTTS=2.3.0, and librosa 0.9.2

```
import librosa

from gtts import gTTS

out_file = "tts_out.mp3"
mytext   = "Bonjour a toi l'ordinateur!"
language = 'fr'
tts      = gTTS(text=mytext, lang=language, slow=False)
tts.save(out_file)
x, sr    = librosa.load(out_file)
print(f"shape       : {x.shape}")
print(f"sample rate : {sr}")
```

Output:

```
shape       : (51333,)
sample rate : 22050
```